# Atom and Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, atom-editor

Using Atom, I'm trying to generate a PDF file from markdown.

I installed `markdown-preview-plus` plugin, which supports pandoc, and then installed pandoc and configured the plugin to use it.

Now, `markdown-preview-plus` does recognize pandoc, but I cannot see any command to generate a PDF. Plugin's web page seems to say nothing about that.. Can you help me?

Comment: I think `markdown-preview-plus` only generates a preview. To generate a PDF you should use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html) itself...

Comment: I see.. So, the alleged pandoc support by the plugin is actually a nonsense??

Comment: Well, it says `markdown-preview` not `markdown-pdf`... but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## markdown-preview-plus

Atom's `markdown-preview-plus` package generates an HTML preview, as @mb21 alluded to. This is clear by the fact that you can right click on the preview and select **Copy as HTML**. With the `Enable Pandoc Parser` option enabled, MPP is indeed using pandoc to generate this HTML preview.

In light of your question, I tried adding the following to the `Pandoc Options: Commandline Arguments` setting in MPP:

`--to=latex, --output=temp.pdf`

**Note 1**: you can't specify `--to=pdf` because pandoc can only generate PDF by first generating a LaTeX file.

**Note 2**: **the above doesn't work** because MPP essentially passes the contents of the editor window through pandoc 'on-the-fly', so you can't really hijack the `--output` setting.

---

## Workarounds

AFAIK, there is no way to get a "live" PDF preview (the way you can get a "live" HTML preview using MPP). This means you will have to build the document whenever you'd like to view what's changed.

Assuming you want to view the PDF in the Atom window, you can install [`pdf-view`](https://atom.io/packages/pdf-view) and open the PDF in a pane, side-by-side with your source. Otherwise, you could simply open the PDF in your favorite PDF reader.

### Build from the command line

As @mb21 suggested, you can build from the command line. I sometimes use BAT/CMD files to store lengthy, or complicated build commands (since I'm on Windows). For example, in my document source directory, I might have `make.cmd`, which contains:

```
pandoc --filter=pandoc-crossref --filter=pandoc-citeproc --smart --listings --number-sections --standalone file.md -o file.pdf
```

Then I run `make.cmd` from the command prompt using `./make.cmd'.

Alternatively, you could use Makefile.

### Build from Atom

Install [`atom-script`](https://atom.io/packages/script). Then, configure your run options (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-O, on Windows) with something along the lines of the following:

```
Command: pandoc
Command Arguments: --filter=pandoc-crossref --filter=pandoc-citeproc --standalone file.md -o file.pdf
```

As you edit your source and would like to update the PDF, you can execute the command via Ctrl-Shift-B

### Build from Atom using `panzer`

You'll still need Atom's `script` package, but you'll also need to get `panzer` which is a utility that helps manage build configurations for pandoc.

---

**Edit:**

### Automatically Build-on-Save via Grunt

Rather than having to press a key combination (e.g. building from command line or using `atom-script`), I thought of automatically building the output PDF upon saving using Grunt. I've captured the basic idea in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/avonmoll/852e6f1ffc6ffd0d58c82ca72cf1dc4c)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same thing right now, only I am using embedded latex mathematical formulae etc.

The markdown-preview-plus gives a fair representation of what I'm likely to see, but I've been running the following command from the command line in order to compile my pdf

```
pandoc -f markdown myfile.md -o pdffile.pdf
```

This works in most simple cases, for trickier ones, or where I want to stitch a few things together, I'm taking my markdown files first to their latex equivalents using a command like

```
pandoc -f markdown+tex_math_dollars+pipe_tables myfile.md -o myfile.tex
```

Which creates a latex version of my original file that I can compile/combine with other latex files, or convert to pdf using

```
pandoc myfile.tex -o myfile.pdf
```

It's supposed to be possible to embed these various scripts into Atom, using the 'scripts' package, but I'm yet to try that - would be great if someone were to post up their methods too in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

I got `pandoc-pdf` toolbar working on **Atom** after installing **Perl** on Windows, though PDF compilation is much slower with "Latexmk".

I recommend using `markdown-preview` enhanced and then use several other options available including pandoc, ebook etc.

Answer (score 0):

[markdown-preview-enhanced](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-enhanced) in Atom has support for PDF-on-save, similar to the [Grunt workflow suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015617/10111155). The `output` command has [several options](https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/#/pandoc?id=export) in addition to PDF, such as MS Word.

Example:

```
---
layout: post
title: tentative tentacles
date: 2020-09-15 15:01
bibliography: bibliography.bib
output: pdf_document
export_on_save:
  pandoc: true
---
```

Comment: I also tried markdown-preview-enhanced, but unfortunately it seems to get confused by math and Pandoc extensions. I cannot get inline equations to work right.